# Problems with loading sounds from Sd-Card

Tags: android, audio, sd-card

I have an application that should load sound from sd card and then play it by clicking the button. When I click the button i get those messages in LogCat : Unable to create external files directory , SoundPool error loading /sound1.mp3 , sample 0 not READY 
And this is my code :

```
import java.io.File;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SoundPool sp;
int mSoundId;
int mStreamId = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "sound1.mp3");
        mSoundId = sp.load(path, 1);

    }
    private String getFullFilePath(Context context, String filename) {  
        File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File file = new File(directory, filename);
        if (!file.canRead()) {
            // error handling
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void button1(View view){


        if (mStreamId != 0) {
            sp.stop(mStreamId);
        }
        mStreamId = sp.play(mSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}
```

My LogCat errors :

```
11-04 18:56:34.499: D/dalvikvm(6547): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 46K, 51% free 2686K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 57ms
11-04 18:56:34.539: W/ApplicationContext(6547): Unable to create external files directory
11-04 18:58:02.129: E/SoundPool(6644): error loading /sound1.mp3
```

Adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Premission gives this error :

```
11-04 19:58:01.729: E/SoundPool(8022): error loading /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.idea/files/sound1.mp3
```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors, so we can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: I posted them..Adding android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE gave me another error..

Comment: You need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to create the folder (or anything) on the sdcard, what are the new errors?

Comment: 11-04 19:58:01.729: E/SoundPool(8022): error loading /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.idea/files/sound1.mp3

Comment: Is `sound1.mp3` actually in this folder?

Comment: I almost feel like upvoting for ignoring the advice and creating a new user account to ask the same question for the 5th time.  But I won't.

Comment: File exists and it is in /mnt/sdcard/ folder. Application should search external storage for sound1.mp3 and load it if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this error:

```
11-04 19:58:01.729: E/SoundPool(8022): error loading /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.idea/files/sound1.mp3
```

You stated:

> File exists and it is in /mnt/sdcard/ folder. Application should search external storage for sound1.mp3 and load it if it exists.

However, `/mnt/sdcard/` is not `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.idea/files/` simply move your `sound1.mp3` file to your applications default sdcard folder and SoundPool will be able to load it.

Comment: I dont wanna  do that..I want applicationn to find sound1.mp3 anywhere on sdcard..

Comment: Android explicitly advises every app to store its data in a organized manner [using these directories](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). However you can clump your data in the sdcard's base folder with [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) instead of `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`